# Importing a variable from AD to map a drive

Tags: powershell-4.0

I'm trying to export the homepath information from AD into a powershell script and map that information. I can pull the information from AD but I cant turn that information into a variable to map the drive. The script looks at a users AD information and is supposed to map a drive with that information if the drive isn't already mapped, then it does a robocopy of data to that drive.
I tried setting the $homedrive variable but I dont think I'm doing it correctly

```
Get-ADUser -Identity $env:username -Properties HomeDirectory |
Select Homedirectory
$homeDirectory = (Get-AdUser -filter {name -eq "$env:username"} -properties *).HomeDirectory
$networkpath = "P:\"
$pathExists = Test-Path -Path $networkpath
If (-not ($pathExists)) {
(new-object -com WScript.Network).MapNetworkDrive("P:",$homeDirectory)
}
robocopy C:\Users\$env:Username\desktop P:\desktop /sec /E /R:3
robocopy C:\Users\$env:Username\favorites P:\favorites /sec /E /R:3
```

I want the $homedrive variable to be whats listed in AD for the user so I can map that drive. When I run the script it just tells me whats in AD but doesnt store the information in the variable.

Answer (score 0):

so i ended up writing it to a csv file then pulling it from the same csv file and it worked

```
Get-ADUser -Identity $env:username -Properties HomeDirectory |
Select -Property HomeDirectory |
Export-CSV 'c:\temp\homedirectory.csv' -NoTypeInformation -encoding UTF8
Import-csv "C:\temp\homedirectory.csv" | foreach-object { 
$homeDirectory = $_.homedirectory
}
$networkpath = "P:\"
$pathExists = Test-Path -Path $networkpath
If (-not ($pathExists)) {
(new-object -com WScript.Network).MapNetworkDrive("P:",$homeDirectory)
}
robocopy C:\Users\$env:Username\desktop P:\desktop /sec /E /R:3
robocopy C:\Users\$env:Username\favorites P:\favorites /sec /E /R:3
```

Comment: $homeDirectory = Get-ADUser -Identity $env:username -Properties HomeDirectory | ForEach-Object {$_.HomeDirectory}